# Axios then callback not working on successful Post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-router

Been working on figuring out user login/register with react and why my axios is not calling `.then` on successful post request to my api.

Server.js

```
//Node packages 
const path = require('path');

//Required NPM Packages
const express                =         require('express'),
      app                    =         express(),
      session                =         require('express-session'),
      cors                   =         require('cors'),
      bodyParser             =         require('body-parser'),
      mongoose               =         require('mongoose'),
      MongoStore             =         require('connect-mongo')(session),
      methodOverride         =         require('method-override'),
      passport               =         require('passport'),
      LocalStrategy          =         require('passport-local');


//MongoDB models.
const Product                =         require('./models/Product');
const User                   =         require('./models/User');

//Routes.
const indexRoute             =         require('./routes/index');
const demoRoute              =         require('./routes/demos');
const blogRoutes             =         require('./routes/blogs');
const userRoutes             =         require('./routes/users');

//Port.
const PORT = 5000;
const DATABASE_URI = require('./config/database');
const mongoOptions = { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true};


//Connect to mongoDB.
mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URI, mongoOptions);

const sessionOptions = {
    secret: 'somesecretword',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}

//set session options 
app.use(session(sessionOptions));



//Setup body-parser.
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


//Allow express/node to accept Cross-origin resource sharing.
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..','client','build')));

//Setup method override.
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

//Congifure passport.

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
})



//register API routes to express.
app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.use('/demos', demoRoute);
app.use('/blogs', blogRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

// //Register React routes to express
app.use('about', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..','client','build')));

app.get('*', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','client','build','index.html'));
})

//listen to established port.
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The server has started on port ${PORT}!`);
});


module.exports = app;
```

login route

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
   console.log('success');
  
   res.json({authenticated:true});
});
```

React front-end function

```
 async function handleRegister(evt){

       //Prevent default form redirect.
       evt.preventDefault();

       //Create a new user objec to pass into axios
       const user = {
           username: username,
           password: password
       }

       //Send axios post request to nodeJS API.
       await axios.post("http://*******/users/register", user)
       .then((res) => {
         console.log(res.data);

      })
       .catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });

       //Push react history back to index page.
      
   }
```

Right now I'm using Passport.js with passport.local.mongoose Strategy and connect-mongo. When I go ahead and post to the login route with the correct users information, the callback on the back end returns success. As per the passport.authenticate method if auth is a success then we `console.log` and send `res.json`.

I've tried to use `res.send, res.json, res.sendStatus` but none of them seem to work. Am I missing some sort of setup with passport? As far as the documentation goes for passport-local-mongoose I shouldn't have to establish a config.

All I want to happen is that when I login I send a redirect to react and push the response route to react-router's history object via history.push(routeUrl);

Comment: You're mixing `async/await` syntax with `.then` syntax. Use one or the other, they aren't compatible

Comment: Are you getting response in your Network tab? Might be an issue with cors. If possible, please share screenshots of console and network tab. Also, /users/register route is missing in your code (in server side).

Comment: So are you saying that your POST request in axios always takes the `.catch` path? It's never resolved?

Comment: I thought with axios in order to ensure that we get a response back we have to use await? Or is that only if we don't do .then after the call? Still learning ins and out of axios and async functions.

Comment: No, `async/await` is used so you can write asynchronous code as if it's synchronous, rather than using `.then` callbacks. It's a general Javascript syntax, nothing to do with axios specifically. If you check axios' Github page, most examples use `.then` but in the example section you can find an example of `async/await` https://github.com/axios/axios#example

Comment: Javascript Promises and `async/await` *can* be used together, but it's uncommon to, and as Jayce444 points out, you should stick to one or the other. You can await the response, or use the chain and process the rest of the function (and eventually the resolved chain).

Comment: OP answered below that it was error on their part. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: @Jayce444 @Drew Reese Thanks for pointing `async/await`, I'll make sure I review and use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Was just an error on my part. Was working with the register function and not the login in  function. The issue wasn't that I wasn't getting a response... Probably a queue for a break.